# Swift and Parse nil on prepareforsegue

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview

Im writing a table view controller using an array from Parse. I need to send data through the segue but I dont know why its always returning nil. I will have to send images and text, but for now *im just taking the text from the label title1 to insert it into a variable type String named example.*

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toDetail" {

        var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! detailViewController

        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView?.indexPathForCell(cell)

        detailScene.example = self.timelineData[indexPath!.row].title1?.text
    }

}
```

For the array I have used:

```
var timelineData : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

And the function `loaddata`, that is used with the function `viewDidAppear`

```
func loaddata () {
    timelineData.removeAllObjects()

    var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "ii")

    findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects, error)->Void in

        if error == nil{
            for object in objects!{
                let ii:PFObject = object as! PFObject
                self.timelineData.addObject(ii)
            }
            let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.timelineData = NSMutableArray(array: array)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share code for `self.timelineData` initialization and filling with data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It should at least get you to the point where you're grabbing the information from the correct cell. I'm assuming your timelineData array is full of text, so that's how I accessed it, by casting it as a String. If it is full of a different type of object you need to cast it differently.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "toDetail" {
        if let detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as? detailViewController {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {
                var object = self.timelineData[indexPath] as! PFObject
                var title = object["title"] as! String
                detailScene.example = title
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In that case the error is: **Type of expression is ambiguous without more context** beacuse of the `detailScene.example.text`

Comment: ok, well what objects are in your timelineData array? Are they strings? Ints? a class? Also, is example a UILabel? Or is it a variable?

Comment: The array holds a class with several columns: Objectid(String), Title(String), Author(Pointer_User), Sights(Int), and more… Thats why im calling to the title

Comment: what's the class name?

Comment: Look at my updated answer. You first have to grab the class from the table cell, then you get your title by taking myClass["title"]. Your class is a dictionary, so you access the title value my making a call to the "title" key of your class. Replace CustomClass with the name of the class object you're trying to access.

Comment: Awesome! You nailed it! That's the solution. I didn't know how to include the PFObject!

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the return value from indexPathForCell is returning nil or a bad value. There are quite a few articles about this function being unreliable.

A common suggestion is to use `indexPathForRowAtPoint(cell.center)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely something wrong with your last line of code:

```
detailScene.example = self.timelineData[indexPath!.row].title1?.text
```

I assume that `self.timelineData` array that holds some data.
If your array contain `String` class you don't need to append `.title1?.text` part.
If your array contain `UILabel` class you need change line to

```
detailScene.example = self.timelineData[indexPath!.row].text
```

because `UILabel` have no property called `title1`.

In general I think this happened because class in `self.timelineData` array have no property called `title1`.

Comment: The array holds a class with several columns: **Objectid(String), Title(String), Author(Pointer_User), Sights(Int), and more…** Thats why im trying calling to title.

Comment: But why you calling `title1`? Your class have such property?

Comment: Title1 is the name of the variable of the UILabel (Contained in the cell) that is receiving the Title from de data base.

Comment: `UILabel` does not have property called `title1`. Did you extend it with custom property? Did you tried to use  `detailScene.example = self.timelineData[indexPath!.row].title`. Pleas post code for creating and initializing `self.timelineData` array and class which it holds.

Comment: No, I havent used custom properties.Using `detailScene.example = self.timelineData[indexPath!.row].title` is returning **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**. The array is working properly, because is perfectly loading every cell.

Comment: Ok. Last final piece - please share code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where you set data from array to label.